# Displaying specific text matching rules of specific workdays of the month

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

so i managed to create a function that will generate a column of workdays of a month (column A). i want to be able to generate text in column B, formatted next to the day ( as shown in the attached picture), following the rules highlighted in the colors.  your help if appreciated

ive tried looking for if function with instr, disregarding formatting, also looking for Case functions, but no success.

below is the code i use to generate the list of workdays

=IF(WORKDAY(G$2-1;ROW(1:1))>G$3;"";WORKDAY(G$2-1;ROW(1:1)))

expected result should be as in columns C & D in the picture attached.

[results in column C & D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OboI.jpg)

Comment: still cant figure out where to start :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not having a single reply in 24h is a sign you should edit your question to make it clear. Seeing column C & D, it looks like what you would get with a pivot table. How to build it is the unclear part ... maybe try to build a big table with column 1+2: combination of all dates with all tasks (regardless whether they are supposed to be done) and column 3 a flag (True/False) evaluating things like: `day (...) < 15` or `weekday(...) = 5`

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to make this pivot table with the combination of column column 1+2 and an example of flag with evaluation

Comment: Simple: you have your 20 days + lets say 25 tasks. So you create a table of 20 x 25 rows with all the possible combinations. Then on the 3rd column, you simply put a formula (1 different formula for each task) saying e.g. "day of the first column is a Monday" or "day of the first column is between the 1st and the 20th". That makes only 25 different formulas that you have to apply on 20 cells each.